# how to replace the header row when reading from Excel- Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I am reading an Excel file, and I want to extract some tables from it, and put the same header for each of them.

It is now taking the first row as the header, while the actual header is the 3rd row.

Here is what I did:

```
new_header = df.iloc[1]
df = df[3:] #choose the data
df.rename(columns = new_header)
```

But it does not change the header row. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:
@EdChum's answer solves the header issue. However I have problem with the format of the header. The header is date in the format of `Month-Year` and I want to keep it that way. But when it reades it, it changes the format to `"2014-01-01 00:00:00"`. I wrote the following peice to fix it, but it only changes the firt cell format and thus, cannot use it as the new header.

```
new_header = datetime.datetime.strptime("2014-01-01 00:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').strftime('%b-%y')
```

Comment: This could be just a string display issue, can you confirm whether the header dtype is str or datetime, thanks

Comment: @EdChum, before I change the format it shows the dtype as object, after that it just prints 'Jan-14' which is the string I gave as the first argument, not the whole row.

Comment: it looks like your values are strings you should be able to convert them using `pd.to_datetime`, try `df.columns = pd.todatetime(df.columns)`

Comment: @EdChum, it didn't change.

Comment: You'll have to post your full data and code then as I can't keep guessing what may be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign directly

```
df.columns = new_header
```

Also you need to assign the result back:

```
df = df.rename(columns = new_header)
```

as `inplace=False` is the default value, most pandas ops return a copy and are not inplace.

If you did

```
df.rename(columns = new_header, inplace=True)
```

it would work

Comment: Thanks. It works, but it changed the format of values. The values are dates in the form of `Jan-14` but it prints it as `2014-01-01 00:00:00`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post data and code, difficult to comment otherwise